# in Java, how to traverse a queue without destroying it, in a simple way?

Tags: java

E.g.

I have a queue

```
void someMethod() {

     history.add(new Sample(time, data));
     ...
     traverse(history);
}

void traverse(Queue<Sample> history) {
     for(int i=0; i<history.size(); i=i+10) {
         history.get(i)...  // ???
     }
}

class Sample {
  long time;
  double data;
}
```

The concerns are that

1. I don't want to destroy this queue by calling `traverse()`.
2. Traverse the queue in a given step, say `10` here.

Any simple and nice solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for (Sample s : history)
    doStuff(s);
```

This is called the enhanced for-loop; you can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 9):

[`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) implements [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), so a simple loop will traverse it:

`for (Sample sample : history)`

An [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is another way to do it, with more control (can destroy it if you want to), but more verbose.

Comment: Nice! I forgot a condition (see the updated question). Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to iterate, use a **for-each loop** or directly a **for loop** with an `Iterator`. This doesn't consume the queue.

If you need to iterate with a step, you can use this pattern. It works generally with any `Iterable`. Putting the skipping into a separate reusable method makes the code more clear than having two nested for loops.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Sample> history = ...
    int step = 10;
    for (Iterator<Sample> it = history.iterator();
            it.hasNext(); skip(it, step - 1)) {
        // note that we skipped 1 less elements than the size of the step
        Sample sample = it.next();
        // stuff
    }
}

static void skip(Iterator<?> iterator, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count && iterator.hasNext(); i++) {
        iterator.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?? I'm the only one so far who also addressed the skipping of elements.

Comment: It seems your code only loop through the first n elements, while OP wants the loop with step size equals n, these are different.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei I disagree. I've tested the code and it works. Only actual problem was that the value of step passed to skip() method has to be smaller by 1 because the obtaining of the next sample also consumes 1 element.

Answer (score -1):

```
LinkedList<Sample> h = (LinkedList<Sample>) history;
for(int i=0; i < h.size(); i+=step) {
    h.get(i).memory ...
}
```

I just realized this approach, haven't tried it yet.

As **nullptr** pointed out, the condition for above code is that the `Queue` is implemented as a `LinkedList`. (which is my case: `Queue<Sample> history = new LinkedList<Sample>();`)

Comment: This will fail if the `Queue` isn't also a `LinkedList`

Comment: @nullptr Nice comment. I agree with you.

Comment: Also, get(index) method on LinkedList has linear time complexity. You're basically iterating the list from its head again and again in every iteration.

Comment: It's fine to implement it that way (besides the time concerns), but you should make the method take a `LinkedList` instead of casting it to one

Comment: @nullptr Nice idea! But that still needs casting which happens during each calling of the `traverse()` method, right?